# Javascript OR variable not working

Tags: javascript

I’m trying to use OR to allow for multiple case responses for a game I am working on.

The code looks like this:

```
  if (password1 == ("kimmy gibbler"||"Kimmy Gibbler"||"kimmy Gibbler"||"Kimmy gibbler"))  

{hypeDocument.functions().addPoint(hypeDocument, element, event);

hypeDocument.showSceneNamed('AllCards')console.log("correct!")return;

} else{document.getElementById("password1").childNodes[1].value ="";console.log("no Dice!”);

};
```

Does anyone have an suggestions as to why only the first response in the list (“kimmy gibbler”) is accepted when a user enters it into the input field?

Comment: That's not how `||` works. `"a" || "b"` will always be `"a"` because a non-empty string is truthy.

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response! What would be the best way of accepting all of those responses without ||?

Comment: `if (password1.toLowerCase() == "kimmy gibbler")` ?

Comment: You can still use `||` but you have to repeat the condition for each test.

Comment: You shouldn't do password protection like that. Everyone who accesses the document need only view your source code to obtain your password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two strings OR'd together like this:

```
"a" || "b"
```

will always resolve to "a".

What you are looking for is this:

```
if (password1 == "kimmy gibbler"
 || password1 == "Kimmy Gibbler"
 || password1 == "kimmy Gibbler"
 || password1 == "Kimmy gibbler")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add all the acceptable phrases to an array, then use `Array.some`

```
var phrases = ["kimmy gibbler", "Kimmy Gibbler", "kimmy Gibbler", "Kimmy gibbler"];

var isValid = phrases.some(function(phrase) { return phrase == password1 });
```

Edit: Thanks @ElGavilan - `Array.some` was added in ECMAScript 5, so its support may be limited across browsers.

Comment: Be careful here; `Array.some` was added in ECMAScript 5, so it's gonna have limited browser support.

Comment: @ElGavilan -- Ahh yep, edited the post to include that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe create an array with those values, then do an if statement with .indexOf to see if it's present in the array? Like so:

```
var solutions = ["kimmy gibbler", "Kimmy Gibbler", "kimmy Gibbler", "Kimmy gibbler"]
if (solutions.indexOf(password1) != -1) {
  hypeDocument.functions().addPoint(hypeDocument, element, event);
  hypeDocument.showSceneNamed('AllCards');
  console.log("correct!");
  return;
} else {
  document.getElementById("password1").childNodes[1].value ="";
  console.log("no Dice!”);
};
```

Comment: This and @tymeJV 's method are both good ways to do this if you have a long list of strings to compare.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to iterate through an array of good answers checking each one.

```
var acceptable = "kimmy gibbler,Kimmy Gibbler,kimmy Gibbler,Kimmy gibbler".split(",");
isCorrectPassword("kImmy gibbler"); // passed: false
isCorrectPassword("kimmy gibbler"); // passed: true

function isCorrectPassword(attempt){
    var pass = false;
    acceptable.forEach(function(v,i){
        if (attempt === v)
            pass = true;
    })
    console.log("passed:",pass);
    return pass;
}
```